# Get Enum by CustomAttribute Value?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a set of enums.  I need to get the enum by it's custom attribute value.

```
namespace Company.Common.Financials
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum DebtType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "credit_card")] CreditCard,
        [EnumMember(Value = "automotive")] Automotive,
        [EnumMember(Value = "student_loan")] StudentLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "401k_loan")] RetirementLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "bank_loan")] BankLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "medical")] Medical,
        [EnumMember(Value = "family")] Family,
        [EnumMember(Value = "real_estate_loan")] RealEstateLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "irs")] IRS,
        [EnumMember(Value = "other")] Other
    }
}
```

How can I find the enum by it's value?  Something like this:

```
DebtType debtType = GetDebtType("student_loan");
```

debtType should equal `DebtType.StudentLoan`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you can do:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vet8z0

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DebtType debtType = GetDebtType("student_loan");
        Console.WriteLine(debtType);
    }
    
    public static DebtType GetDebtType(string debtType)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(DebtType))
            .Cast<DebtType>()
            .FirstOrDefault(a => EnumExtensions.GetAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>(a).Value == debtType);
    }
    
    public enum DebtType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "credit_card")] CreditCard,
        [EnumMember(Value = "automotive")] Automotive,
        [EnumMember(Value = "student_loan")] StudentLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "401k_loan")] RetirementLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "bank_loan")] BankLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "medical")] Medical,
        [EnumMember(Value = "family")] Family,
        [EnumMember(Value = "real_estate_loan")] RealEstateLoan,
        [EnumMember(Value = "irs")] IRS,
        [EnumMember(Value = "other")] Other
    }
    
    class EnumMemberAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public EnumMemberAttribute()
        {
        }
    }
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum value)
        where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
            return type.GetField(name)
                .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different tack to what you were trying.  First I defined your `EnumMemberAttribute` so I had something to work with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class EnumMemberAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and I created your `DebtType` enum:

```
public enum DebtType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "credit_card")] CreditCard,
    [EnumMember(Value = "automotive")] Automotive,
    [EnumMember(Value = "student_loan")] StudentLoan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "401k_loan")] RetirementLoan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "bank_loan")] BankLoan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "medical")] Medical,
    [EnumMember(Value = "family")] Family,
    [EnumMember(Value = "real_estate_loan")] RealEstateLoan,
    [EnumMember(Value = "irs")] IRS,
    [EnumMember(Value = "other")] Other
}
```

Then I created this class.  Originally, it was just a static method, but I figured if you were going to use this more than once, it was best to amortize the reflection work (and cache things in a Dictionary):

```
public class EnumByAttribute<T> where T: struct, Enum
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, T> _enumDictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();
    public EnumByAttribute()
    {
        var enumType = typeof(T);
        var memberInfos = enumType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var members = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        Debug.Assert(memberInfos.Length == members.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < memberInfos.Length; ++i)
        {
            var enumMemberAttribute = memberInfos[i].GetCustomAttributes<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (enumMemberAttribute != null)
            {
                _enumDictionary.Add(enumMemberAttribute.Value, (T)members.GetValue(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TryGetByEnumMemberValue(string enumMemberValue, out T enumValue)
    {
        return _enumDictionary.TryGetValue(enumMemberValue, out enumValue);
    }
}
```

Finally, to test this, I did the following:

```
var test = new EnumByAttribute<DebtType>();
var success = test.TryGetByEnumMemberValue("401k_loan", out var val);
```

and it worked the way I expected.  I used the standard `TryGetXxx` pattern since I figured that you really wanted to know if it worked or not.  It would be easy to just write a `Get` method (that, I'm assuming should throw on failure) using the code above.